# Хранение нескольких целочисленных значений в одном поле таблицы

Tags: mysql, innodb

Есть таблица, в которой храниться информация о товарах магазина. В поле `similar` хранятся id-шники похожих товаров той же таблицы в виде строки (например: "42,526,3542,62359", 0-64 штук).
Товаров достаточно много, пользователей на сайте много, обновляется поле "similar" часто. Поэтому похожие товары для пущего быстродействия хранятся в той же таблице.

```
CREATE TABLE `goods`(
`id` INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`price` FLOAT UNSIGNED NULL,
...
`similar` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
) 
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Все работает хорошо и достаточно быстро. Но строковые значения занимают больше места, чем те же значения в INT-типе. Имеется ли возможность хранить несколько (0-64) целочисленных значений типа INT(4 бита) в одном поле таблицы InnoDB не строкой?

Создавать отдельную таблицу с id-шниками не предлагать.

Comment: На Си нет никаких проблем в упаковке 8-ми 4-битных полей в 32-битный int с помощью сдвигов и операции `|` (соответственно извлечь, используя сдвиг и операцию `&`). / Если SQL позволяет аналогичные действия, то можно

Comment: А для каких целей они там хранятся ? Есть ли хоть один sql запрос, где это поле встречается в where, т.е. с ним выполняются какие либо манипуляции ? Если нет, то можно сделать поле например varbinary и значения для него упаковывать на клиенте как двоичный массив и распаковывать там же.